# Azure Recovery services scheduled tasks keep going disabled

Tags: azure, backup, windows-server-2019

I have installed Azure Recovery Services (MARS) onto a 2019 server. I can fully configure it using the GUI, but the scheduled backups just don't run.
I can run the back manually and it runs perfectly and completes quickly; however, when I try to use the scheduler, it doesn't run.

I have checked the Task Scheduler and the job keeps switching to disabled with the notification:

```
User "System"  disabled Task Scheduler task "\Microsoft\OnlineBackup\Microsoft-OnlineBackup"
```

When I installed the application, I changed the default path to `C:\Domain Services`  to keep them separate, is this where it went wrong?

I have other servers on the backup platform which are not having any issues at all, I have also tried the steps in:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-mars-troubleshoot#backups-dont-run-according-to-schedule

And also

https://dirteam.com/bas/2019/01/09/the-mysterious-case-of-azure-backup-agent-not-running-its-schedule/

But it is not fixing the issue.

I am completely out of ideas, hoping that somebody can help me!

Answer (score 0):

Change the settings in the task scheduler for Online Backups. See the snippet below.

[image]

Comment: Hi,
Thank for coming back to me. I have tried it and it is still disabling!

Does anybody have any other ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea how, but the system is now working correctly and not being disabled. I tried to remove all the MARS software on the machine and re-installed it and it now works correctly and has been backing up for a few weeks now.

Thank you for all your assistance.